# Host para app Android en proceso de desarrollo

Tags: android, base-de-datos, app

Estoy desarrollando con un equipo una app android con una base de datos de clientes. Cada cliente tendrá su perfil individual.

Durante la etapa de desarrollo, el equipo no estará en el mismo lugar físico y necesito la manera de que todos tengan acceso al proyecto y su base de datos para poder desarrollar. Utilizaremos Java + Android Studio.

Para los archivos y documentos utilizaremos Google Drive pero no sé si será correcto guardar el proyecto allí junto con la DB o contratar un host (definitivo o momentaneo) y almacenar todo ahí para que mi equipo lo pueda utilizar.

Cuando el proyecto este finalizado se publicará en el Play Store.

Recomendaciones? Gracias!

Comment: Yo de momento empezaría por Un repositorio GitHub o bitbucket, así tu equipo deslocalización puede trabajar sobre ese proyecto. En el repositorio podrías poner un dockerfile para generar un entorno de servidores en cada local

Comment: Investigaré mas sobre el tema pero me has dado una dirección para encaminar mi proyecto. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score -1):

Yo usaria un repositorio Git, por ejemplo bitbucket es gratis hasta 5 usuarios en el mismo proyecto, git es mil veces mejor para tener versionado el codigo.

Para la BD, supongo que tendréis que pillar un hosting y tener una bd en mySQL, y deberíais tener una API REST para obtener de ahi los datos de clietnes etc, con lo cual te diría de utilizar symfony o cualquier otro framework que use como ORM doctrine, doctrine es una herramienta para administrar bases de datos, donde tu en php creas un modelo y con doctrine mapeas ese modelo en una tabla, te pongo un ejemplo:

Digamos que tu creas un modelo cliente con sus datos en php, llamas al comando doctrine:schema:update y creas la tabla clientes en tu sql, subes al repositorio el modelo nuevo con git.

Ahora tu compi, se descarga del repo el modelo nuevo, y con el comando doctrine:schema:update se crea la tabla en su mysql EN LOCALHOST, para poder trabajar con el.

Doctrine tiene un comando para rellenar con datos "falsos" las tablas y poder trabajar con datos ficticios.

En resumen: un orm como doctrine, symfony lo lleva incluido, y para compartir archivos sea de android, php o de cualquier programa yo trabajaría con git y un repositorio gratuito en la web.

Comment: Bueno, muchas gracias. Tu comentario fue de mucha ayuda. Investigaré bien sobre el tema.